# Left padding is being applied out of nowhere (paranormal CSS declaration)?

Tags: jquery, css

If you use Firebug inspector, and hover `#jimgMenu ul` you will see that it has left padding but no css rule related to it:

http://www.alohatechsupport.net/examples/image-menu-1.html

Where is the left padding coming from? Why I can't see the origin?

EDIT:

If you click in Layout/Metrics it says that `#jimgMenu ul` has left padding = 40px;

But again I can't find where it that padding coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User agent stylesheet is being applied with the following padding (in chrome)

```
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

thats why its always useful to use a css reset to remove all paddings and margins specific to each browser

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Weird I'm using the same css reset

Comment: I cant find it anywhere the page? only stylesheet your linking  to is"jimgMenu.css" and it has no reset

Comment: that one is not my page. Here in my localhost I'm using one. But well the problem was found. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

an <ul>-Element has also an indent to be proof that its elements aren't displayed outside of the list

[Unordered List (<ul>) default indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781014/unordered-list-ul-default-indent)

You can set own padding for ul to overwrite this indent. <-- I tried this in firebug and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS reset?

http://www.cssreset.com/downloads/css-resets/eric-meyer-reset-css/eric-meyer-reset.css

Will reset all browser styles to 0 margin and padding.