# Center-align <li> in vertical <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been trying to work this out for hours now, so here goes:

**I want my li items to be centered within the ul.** **For some reason they seem to be aligned right.** ie. I want the red dashed box to be centered within the green solid one.

I've tried margin: 0 auto;, text-align:center, etc. with no luck.

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgn0fLL/)

The code:

```
.leftbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
  }

  #navMenu {        
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }

  #navList {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  #navList li {
    border: 1px dashed red;
  }


</style>
```

```
<div class="leftbar">
  <img src="http://goo.gl/kBrNqn">
  <div id="navMenu">
    <ul id="navList">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>People</li>
      <li>Places</li>
      <li>Things</li>
      <li>BLOG</li>
      <br/>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reset css file (for more optimization) or you can add this in your css :

CSS :

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/rzgn0fLL/1/**

Comment: Excellent! Can you tell me why this works? Is this standard practice to include this rule in all stylesheets? What are the default values for these fields if not 0?

Comment: Just so that OP understands, UL elements have an added indent/padding by default. It was made like that so that the bullets will not end up outside the list itself. [SOURCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781014/unordered-list-ul-default-indent)

Comment: All browsers add some specific native properties, like padding, margin, ... css reset file reset all tags properties, `*` operator select all tags, it's better and more fast to use reset css file.