# How to properly align two elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

Need some help with (what is probably somewhat basic) CSS. I need to align to different  elements, one next to the other. If you take a look...

[image: bad alignment]

...you can see what my current code is producing. It is obviously not what I want... They are currently cut off on the sides, and they don't look good next to each other...

Current code:

```
#bullets {
display: inline-block;
width: 60%;
float: left;
}

#quotes {
display: inline-block;
width: 40%;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: your link says "error 404 : file not found"!

Comment: Whoops. Link is fixed. Sorry!

Comment: maybe you need to reset css ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252678/center-align-li-in-vertical-ul/25252752#25252752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/jhgcm6ym/

HTML:

```
<div id="bullets">Left</div>
<div id="quotes">Right</div>
```

CSS

```
#bullets {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
#quotes {
    margin-left: 60%;
}
```

`display: inline-block;` and `float` do not play together, as the floated element will become a box block element by default: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position

This is a very good information, you should read: http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead you might want to consider floating `#quotes` left as well:

```
 #quotes {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      float: left;
 }
```

From here you can clean things up by adjusting the margins in bullets:

```
 #bullets {
      margin: auto 2%;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 55%;
      float: left;
 }
```

Hope this helps!

A great place that you can draw information from is by looking at how other grid systems are put together. Consider the following snippet:

```
 .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 98%; /* width of container */
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
 }

 .container .column,
 .container .columns {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 1%; /* spacing between columns */
      margin-right: 1%; /* spacing between columns */
 }

 .container .one.column,
 .container .one.columns { width: 4.25%; }
 .container .two.columns { width: 10.5%; }
 /* and so on... however many columns you want */

.container:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Notice how everything is floated to the `left` and the display is set to `inline`. We create a little bit of separation between our `.columns` by adding left and right margins. This will create a good amount of space between our `.columns` so we don't run into issue like you experienced. Also, [this](http://grids.heroku.com/) might be a good resource to learn more about grids and how they're set up.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to update the `width`. Check it now.

Comment: Also, there may be border issues. I see an orange border and since I can't see the other CSS or HTML it's hard to tell why it's getting cut off. `box-sizing: border-box` may help.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a solution for you problem..

```
.container-block{
    padding:20px;
}
```

**.container-block** is the parent class for **bullets** and **quotes**