# CSS how do i center an UL inside a wrapper?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am having trouble centering my ul that contains icons of facebook, twitter,  and linkedin. in my page the icons are more towards the right and are not centering. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(macbook2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.header-dark {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -250px;
}
.selfie {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background-image: url(selfie.jpg);*/
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid #6f6f70;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ion-social-facebook {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ion-social-twitter {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ion-social-linkedin {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <div class="header-dark">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selfie"></div>
      <h2>Name</h2>
      <ul>
        <!--this is what i am trying to center-->
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-linkedin"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I added your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/pw5fx7ym/ 
it seems the list is centered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center <ul> <li> into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708054/center-ul-li-into-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your centering is working. Just use `padding: 0;` on the ul to remove the left [standard padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781014/unordered-list-ul-default-indent) of [unordered lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(macbook2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.header-dark {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -250px;
}
.selfie {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background-image: url(selfie.jpg);*/
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid #6f6f70;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ion-social-facebook {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ion-social-twitter {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ion-social-linkedin {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <div class="header-dark">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="selfie"></div>
      <h2>Name</h2>
      <ul>
        <!--this is what i am trying to center-->
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="ion-social-linkedin"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
  </nav>
</header>
```